# SQL Server: use function after certain value in table

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I am trying to find the time difference between two certain points in stored conversations. These points can differ in each conversation which makes it difficult for me. I need the time difference between the Agent's message and the first EndUser response after it.

In the example in CaseNr 1234 below I need the time difference between MessageNrs 3&4, 5&6 and 7&8.
In CaseNr 2345 I need the time difference between MessageNrs 3&4, 5&6, 7&8 and 10&11.
In CaseNr 4567 I need the time difference between 2&3 and 4&5.

As is shown, the order Agent & EndUser can differ in each conversation as well as the positions these types are in.

Is there a way to calculate the time difference the way I have described it in SQL server?

[image]

Comment: Images of data really don't help us help you. Take the time to post your data as DDL and DML statements. Also don't forget to include the expected results you are after *and* your attempt(s) (with an explanation of why they didn't work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should help you.

```
with t(MessageNr,CaseNr,Type, AgentTime, EndUserTime) as
(
    select 
        t1.MessageNr,
        t1.CaseNr,
        t1.Type,
        t1.EntryTime,
        (select top 1 t2.EntryTime 
        from [Your_Table] as t2 
        where t1.CaseNr = t2.CaseNr
            and t2.[Type] = 'EndUser'
            and t1.EntryTime < t2.EntryTime
        order by t2.EntryTime) as userTime
    from [Your_Table] as t1
    where t1.[Type] = 'Agent'
)
select t.*, DATEDIFF(second, AgentTime, EndUserTime)
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the logic you require is the time difference between an `Agent` row and the immediately following `EndUser` row.

**You can do this with `LEAD`, which will be more performant than the use of self-joins.**

```sql
SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(second, t.EntryTime, t.NextTime) TimeDifference
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD(CASE WHEN t.[Type] = 'EndUser' THEN t.EntryTime END) NextTime
    FROM myTable t
) t
WHERE t.[Type] = 'Agent'
  AND t.NextTime IS NOT NULL
```